# Why is this creating two e-mails per workbook?

Tags: vba

I am taking a worksheet from a master workbook and creating a separate workbook for each one
These workbooks are then saved into a folder and then each workbook is added to an e-mail.
Each workbook is creating 2 e-mails but I can't see why from the code?

```
Sub MoveandSaveWorkBooks()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wK As Worksheet

For Each wK In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wK.name = "Master Data" Then
    ElseIf wK.name = "Button" Then
    Else
    wK.Copy

    Selection.RowHeight = 84.75
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWorkbook.Password = UserInput
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wK.name & ".xlsx"


    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As Object

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NewMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With NewMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = "" 



    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .display   


    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set NewMail = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing

    ActiveWorkbook.Close True


End If
Next wK

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: That `If` condition needs to be inverted. `If {condition} Then {do nothing} Else {do stuff}` should be `If {not-condition} Then {do stuff}`.

Comment: Have you tried breaking (F9) inside the loop to examine what the 2nd workbook was? Is the loop running twice? Also consider extracting the body into smaller, specialized procedures that only deal with one thing: debugging the higher-level logic would be much easier without all the low-level implementation details in the way.